# NDSolve:PDE system, initial-boundary value problem:warning:NDSolve::mconly: For the method NDSolve`IDA, only machine real code is available

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages, boundary-conditions

I tried to NDSolve the PDE system
$$\partial_t w =x\cdot w\quad\quad\partial_z x=w$$
for
$$(t,z)\in[0,1]\times[0,\pi]$$
with boundary conditions
$$x(t,0)=w(t,0)=w(t,\pi)=0$$
and initial conditions
$$w(0,z)=\sin z\quad\quad x(0,z)=1-\cos z$$
Here's my code:

```
s = NDSolve[{D[w[t, z], t] == w[t, z]*x[t, z], 
   D[x[t, z], z] == w[t, z], w[0, z] == Sin[z], x[0, z] == 1 - Cos[z],
    w[t, 0] == 0, w[t, π] == 0, x[t, 0] == 0}, {w , x}, {t, 0, 
   1}, {z, 0, π}]
```

Mathematica displays the following warning:

> "NDSolve::mconly: For the method NDSolve`IDA, only machine real code
>   is available. Unable to continue with complex values or beyond
>   floating-point exceptions."

I would appreciate any help on how to overcome this error or solve numerically this kind of PDE system anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quasilinear hyperbolic system of equations. Not all initial data is valid, `w=0` should be excluded from the initial data. An example of solving the problem

```
s = NDSolve[{D[w[t, z], t] == w[t, z]*x[t, z], 
   D[x[t, z], z] == w[t, z], w[0, z] == 1, x[0, z] == 1 - Cos[z], 
   w[t, 0] == 1, w[t, \[Pi]] == 1, x[t, 0] == 0}, {w, x}, {t, 0, 
   1}, {z, 0, \[Pi]}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MinPoints" -> 80, "MaxPoints" -> 100, 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}];
{ContourPlot[Evaluate[w[t, z] /. s], {t, 0, 1}, {z, 0, \[Pi]}, 
  Contours -> 20, ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotLabel -> "w", 
  FrameLabel -> {"t", "z"}, PlotLegends -> Automatic], 
 ContourPlot[Evaluate[x[t, z] /. s], {t, 0, 1}, {z, 0, \[Pi]}, 
  Contours -> 20, ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotLabel -> "x", 
  FrameLabel -> {"t", "z"}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]}
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Thanks for great help! Also: how can I see that  boundary condition $w(t,0)=0$ is invalid?

Comment: @user61386 It is necessary to bring the system to a second order equation using $x=w_t/w$ and then $x_z=w=(w_t/w)_z$

Comment: My only  problem is that with the  initial conditions used above, i.e. $w(0,z)=1$ and $x(0,z)=1-\cos z$, the PDE system equation $\partial_t x =w$ seems to fail for $t=0$.

Comment: Sorry, where does this equation come from?

Comment: In fact it is an equation I constructed as an example problem. Costructing simple test problems is very helpfull in mathematica. Therefore the ability to costruct valid initial boundary conbitions is of vital importance.

Comment: So, I thought that any initial condition for $x$ should obey  the condition $\partial_z x= w$.

Comment: Initial and boundary conditions must be consistent.

Comment: Probably I am missing something but I cannot find any inconsistency between the  boundary and initial conditions I proposed. I  need some help with this.

Comment: There is another problem. In a quasilinear hyperbolic system, discontinuous solutions are formed similar to shock waves in a compressible medium. These solutions depend on the initial conditions.

Comment: OK, thanks for valuable help and time.

Comment: Actually `NDSolve` doesn't analyse the equation system properly, the boundary condition for `x` isn't used at all. Try the following sample, notice I've introduced an empty function `bcx`:  `Clear[bcx]; s = 
 NDSolve[{D[w[t, z], t] == w[t, z]*x[t, z], D[x[t, z], z] == w[t, z], w[0, z] == 1, 
   x[0, z] == 1 - Cos[z], w[t, 0] == 1, w[t, \[Pi]] == 1, x[t, 0] == bcx[t]}, {w, x}, {t,
    0, 1}, {z, 0, \[Pi]}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MinPoints" -> 80, 
      "MaxPoints" -> 100, "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}];`