# Mathematica and IBVP mixing temporal and spatial derivatives

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, warning-messages, numerical-value

The following   PDE's-system-solving code

```
 cn = 10^-1; zmin = -1*cn; tmax = 1*cn;
    IBVP = NDSolve[{D[w[t, z], t] == 
    D[q[t, z], z] + w[t, z]*D[w[t, z], z], 
    D[q[t, z], t] == D[w[t, z], z] + w[t, z]*D[q[t, z], z], 
    w[0, z] == 0, w[t, 0] == 0, q[0, z] == 1, 
    q[t, 0] == Cos[t]^2}, {w, q}, {t, 0, tmax}, {z, 0, zmin}, 
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MinPoints" -> 80, "MaxPoints" -> 100}}];
    Plot3D[w[t, z] /. IBVP, {t, 0, tmax}, {z, 0, zmin}]
```

is just fine for Mathematica. However when the PDE
$$\partial_zB(t,z)=0$$
is added to the system along with trivial initial-boundary conditions
$$B(0,z)=0\qquad B(t,0)=0$$
i.e. the code becomes

```
cn = 10^-1; zmin = -1*cn; tmax = 1*cn;
IBVP2 = NDSolve[{D[w[t, z], t] == 
     D[q[t, z], z] + w[t, z]*D[w[t, z], z], 
    D[q[t, z], t] == D[w[t, z], z] + w[t, z]*D[q[t, z], z], 
    D[B[t, z], z] == 0, w[0, z] == 0, w[t, 0] == 0, q[0, z] == 1, 
    q[t, 0] == Cos[t]^2, B[0, z] == 0, B[t, 0] == 0}, {w, q, B}, {t, 
    0, tmax}, {z, 0, zmin}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MinPoints" -> 80, "MaxPoints" -> 100}}];
Plot3D[w[t, z] /. IBVP2, {t, 0, tmax}, {z, 0, zmin}]
```

Mathematica displays the following error

> Warning: an insufficient number of boundary conditions have been 
>   specified for the direction of independent variable z. Artificial 
>   boundary effects may be present in the solution. >>

It is conceivable that one can solve the IBVP  for $B(t,z)$   seperately and get $B(t,z)=0$.

However it may be the case that `D[B[t, z], z]` has a dependence on `w[t, z]` or `q[t, z]` with `D[w[t, z], t]` having also a dependance on `B[t, z]` in which case the PDE's are coupled and can not be integrated indpendently from one another.

So it is technically important to find out what is wrong with `IBVP2`.

I would appreciate any help on the above.

PS: My real concern is to tackle problems where the PDE's are coupled and mix temporal and spatial derivatives for example
$$\partial_tw=e^B\cdot\partial_zq+w\cdot\partial_zw\qquad\partial_tq=e^B\cdot\partial_zw+w\cdot\partial_zq\qquad\partial_zB=w\cdot e^q$$ 
so I need an answer that can be generalised in this case.

I am not sure whether Μathematica can  tackle problems of this kind in general. However it is hard to believe that it crushes for this -apparently- trivial case.

Comment: In short, `NDSolve` can't handle PDE that doesn't involve **pure** derivative of time well (at least now) . Similar problems: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/184281/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/163923/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/183745/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118194/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133731/1871

Comment: However there are some exceptions when `NDSolve` can handle PDE that doesn't involve pure derivative of time. Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/186777/ndsolvepde-system-initial-boundary-value-problemwarningndsolvemconly-for)  post?

Comment: Please notice Alex has modified i.c. and b.c. drastically in that example, which is usually impossible in real cases.

Comment: How can such a trivial example confuse Mathematica? There must be some way to fix the code.

Comment: If you just want to fix the `bcart`, it's simple, just modify the additional equation to `D[D[B[t, z], z] == 0, t]`. Then you'll find _Mathematica_ still can't solve the system, and this is where the real trouble begins. Also, notice in Alex's answer linked above, `NDSolve` actually doesn't analyse the PDE system correctly, either. For more information, check my comment under that answer.

Comment: It confuses _Mathematica_ because your last equations for B simply imply that B does not depend on z. There are an infinite number of functions of time that will satisfy your BC/IC.  You will need another expression for B in terms of q and w that can be, fortunately, evaluated at any point in space.  I posted an answer [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1575334?p_p_auth=8yc2L5Nw) where the divergence of a dependent variable equaled zero and I solved it following [The Numerical Method of Lines Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html).

Comment: I thought that BC/IC `B[0, z] == 0, B[t, 0] == 0` along with PDE `D[B[t, z], z] == 0` lead to $B(t,z)=0$. How can an infinite number of functions satisfy these?

Comment: You are correct.  The only function that satisfies is B=0, since B is a function of t only.

Comment: In your PS, I think your current BCs and ICs will always make everything zero except for q at the boundary (both B and w are zero initially making it impossible to evolve).  Can you set up a case with your desired BCs and ICs?

Comment: @Tim Laska I modified the exemplified PDE's system. I think it's ok now.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple modification that fits the occasion. You just have to remove the condition `B[t,0] == 0` . Then the message appears, but the two solutions for `w[t,z], q[t,z]` although not identical, but not very different.

```
cn = 10^-1; zmin = -1*cn; tmax = 1*cn;
IBVP = NDSolve[{D[w[t, z], t] == 
     D[q[t, z], z] + w[t, z]*D[w[t, z], z], 
    D[q[t, z], t] == D[w[t, z], z] + w[t, z]*D[q[t, z], z], 
    w[0, z] == 0, w[t, 0] == 0, q[0, z] == 1, 
    q[t, 0] == Cos[t]^2}, {w, q}, {t, 0, tmax}, {z, 0, zmin}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MinPoints" -> 80, "MaxPoints" -> 100}}];



IBVP2 = NDSolve[{D[w[t, z], t] == 
     D[q[t, z], z] + w[t, z]*D[w[t, z], z], 
    D[q[t, z], t] == D[w[t, z], z] + w[t, z]*D[q[t, z], z], 
    D[B[t, z], z] == 0, w[0, z] == 0, w[t, 0] == 0, q[0, z] == 1, 
    q[t, 0] == Cos[t]^2, B[0, z] == 0}, {w, q, B}, {t, 0, tmax}, {z, 
    0, zmin}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MinPoints" -> 80, "MaxPoints" -> 100}}];


{Plot3D[w[t, z] /. IBVP, {t, 0, tmax}, {z, 0, zmin}, PlotRange -> All,
   Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue, AxesLabel -> {"t", "z", "w"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "IBVP"], 
 Plot3D[w[t, z] /. IBVP2, {t, 0, tmax}, {z, 0, zmin}, 
  PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "z", "w"}, PlotLabel -> "IBVP2"], 
 Plot[{w[t, -t] /. IBVP, w[t, -t] /. IBVP2}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"IBVP", "IBVP2"}]}
```

[image: fig1]

Consider a solution with b.c. `B[t, 0] == 0`

```
IBVP1 = NDSolve[{D[w[t, z], t] == 
     D[q[t, z], z] + w[t, z]*D[w[t, z], z], 
    D[q[t, z], t] == D[w[t, z], z] + w[t, z]*D[q[t, z], z], 
    D[B[t, z], z] == 0, w[0, z] == 0, w[t, 0] == 0, q[0, z] == 1, 
    q[t, 0] == Cos[t]^2, B[0, z] == 0, B[t, 0] == 0}, {w, q, B}, {t, 
    0, tmax}, {z, 0, zmin}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MinPoints" -> 80, "MaxPoints" -> 100}}];
{Plot3D[q[t, z] /. IBVP, {t, 0, tmax}, {z, 0, zmin}, PlotRange -> All,
   Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue, AxesLabel -> {"t", "z", "q"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "IBVP"], 
 Plot3D[q[t, z] /. IBVP1, {t, 0, tmax}, {z, 0, zmin}, 
  PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "z", "q"}, PlotLabel -> "IBVP1"], 
 Plot[{q[t, -t] /. IBVP, q[t, -t] /. IBVP1}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"IBVP", "IBVP1"}]}
```

In this case, the two solutions `IBVP, IBVP1` for `q[t,z]` diverge. But the two solutions `IBVP2, IBVP1` for `B[t,z]` are the same `B[t,z]=0`.

[image: fig2]

I found a method for solving a system of equations in the general case. We use the explicit Euler in time and the standard solver for `z`. We solve the example given by the author as "My real concern":

```
zmin = -1/10; t0 = 1/20; tmax = 63*t0;
W[0][z_] := 0
Q[0][z_] := 1
B[0][z_] := 0
Do[{W[t], Q[t], B[t]} = 
   NDSolveValue[{(w[z] - W[t - t0][z])/t0 == 
      Exp[b[z]]*D[q[z], z] + w[z]*D[w[z], z], (q[z] - Q[t - t0][z])/
       t0 == Exp[b[z]]*D[w[z], z] + w[z]*D[q[z], z], 
     D[b[z], z] == w[z]*Exp[q[z]], w[0] == 0, q[0] == Cos[t]^2, 
     b[0] == 0}, {w, q, b}, {z, 0, zmin}, Method -> "BDF"], {t, t0, 
   tmax, t0}];
{ListPlot3D[
  Flatten[Table[{t, z, W[t][z]}, {t, 0, tmax, t0}, {z, 0, zmin, 
     zmin/50}], 1], Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
  ColorFunction -> "SouthwestColors", AxesLabel -> {"t", "z", "w"}], 
 ListPlot3D[
  Flatten[Table[{t, z, Q[t][z]}, {t, 0, tmax, t0}, {z, 0, zmin, 
     zmin/50}], 1], Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
  ColorFunction -> "SouthwestColors", AxesLabel -> {"t", "z", "q"}], 
 ListPlot3D[
  Flatten[Table[{t, z, B[t][z]}, {t, 0, tmax, t0}, {z, 0, zmin, 
     zmin/50}], 1], Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
  ColorFunction -> "SouthwestColors", AxesLabel -> {"t", "z", "B"}]}
```

[image: fig3]

Comment: My real concern is the case when the PDE's are coupled. In that case not giving b.c. for $B$ would be mathematically problematic. So what alternatives do I have?

Comment: Your real case should be studied but not by this example. In this example, Mathematica adds artificial boundary conditions, so you need to remove b.c. `B[t,0] == 0`.

Comment: The solution for `B` in `IBVP2` is almost meaningless, isn't it? Without the b.c. in `z` direction, solution for `D[B[t, z], z] == 0` won't be determined.

Comment: Check that the numerical solution `B = 0` is obtained with and without b.c. `B[t,0] == 0`. See update.

Comment: Yeah, but that's because OP happens to choose `B[t, 0]  == 0` as b.c., what if the b.c. is `B[t, 0] == t`?

Comment: But this is a completely different problem. It has a different solution.

Comment: Not that different. Notice the variable `B` is not coupled with `q` and `w`, so it should be uniquely determined by `{D[B[t, z], z] == 0, B[t, 0] == (* something *)}`. `NDSolve` happens to find `B[t, z] == 0` in `IBVP2`, but it's no more than a  coincidence.

Comment: @xzczd I agree, but I still can’t find an algorithm for solving coupled PDE.

Comment: Alex Trunev, what do you think of   this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189690/ibvp-mixing-temporal-and-spatial-derivatives-close-to-a-solution)?Probably it is a general method to solve first order IBVP problems that mixa spatial and temporal derivatives.

Comment: @dkstack There are many methods for solving linear equations. But for non-linear equations one has to invent new methods.

Comment: I think that the method in the post can be applied to the non-linear "real-concern" problem in this post. However I have not yet achieved to increase accuracy. That is why I test the numerical against the analytical solution. What do you think?